# How to make the menu displayed in the template10

Tags: xaml, uwp, template10

How to make the menu displayed in the template10 in Hamburg as splitview in the MySplitView.IsPaneOpen =! MySplitView.IsPaneOpen;

[image]

[image]

why ?...

Comment: You want to hide/show the `SplitView` in template 10? And what do your images suggest here? I can't see any relatives between them.

Comment: i want a hamburger menu Sample  template10

Comment: If you installed the template 10, you can create a hambuger template 10 demo, it is the very basic hambuger menu sample of temeplate 10.

Comment: `return Task.CompletedTask;`  I would say you have other underlying issues that aren't right with basic setup of hamburger-T10, suggest looking at samples..